# How to long press and select an item from popup menu without lifting the finger?

Tags: android, android-menu

A gif is much more suitable for demonstration in this case:

[image: NULL]

As you can see in the gif above, I can click on the menu  items by a long press and hold gesture and I can also select items without lifting my finger. How can I go about creating something like this with any type of `View`, not just toolbar/actionbar menu items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging through the docs, I got the answer myself. You have to do something like this:

```
 PopupMenu myPopup = new PopupMenu(context, myAnchor);
 myAnchor.setOnTouchListener(myPopup.getDragToOpenListener());
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html#getDragToOpenListener()